# Stored Procedure with both input and output parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with 3 columns: `username`, `password` and `permission`. I am trying to write a stored procedure to accept `@username` as an input parameter and then output a parameter `@permission`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More might be needed, but according to your question, this is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPermission]
    @userName varchar(50),
    @permission int output
AS
BEGIN

    select @permission = PERMISSION from USERS where UserName = @userName

END;
```

EDIT:

Another option is to create a function, example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPermission](@userName [varchar(50)])
RETURNS [int] 
AS 
BEGIN

    declare @permission int

    select @permission = PERMISSION from USERS where UserName = @userName

    return @permission

END;
```

Comment: would it be better to create a stored function with a returnvalue? Does it make much difference to return a resultSet instead?

Comment: btw. if you (pikk) want to compare the password I would advice you to store them hashed... [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)

Comment: Hm, i am trying to run in Visual Studio 2010 using C# and the Debugger says "Procedure or function 'sp_getPermission' expects parameter '@permission', which was not supplied.". But it is the output, what do I have to supply?

Comment: @pikk: you have to declare the parameter anyway, but, after the SP executes, the value will change.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Gustavo F point, the ParameterDirection of the output parameter should be set to ParameterDirection.Output.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.direction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROC SP_ORDERS AS BEGIN SELECT DISTINCT E.EmployeeID,E.FirstName+SPACE(3)+E.LastName AS CUTNAME,E.City,ET.TerritoryDescription,P.ProductName, OD.Discount,SUM(OD.Quantity*OD.UnitPrice)AS TOTAL FROM [DimOrder Details] OD  JOIN DimOrders O ON OD.OrderID=O.OrderID JOIN DimProducts P ON OD.ProductID=P.ProductID JOIN DimEmployees E ON O.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID JOIN DimCustomers C ON O.CustomerID=C.CustomerID JOIN DimEmployeeTerritories ET ON E.EmployeeID=ET.EmployeeID GROUP BY E.EmployeeID,E.FirstName,E.LastName,E.City,ET.TerritoryDescription,P.ProductName,OD.Discount END
```